# Convert from CSV to XLSX and save with same file name

Tags: vba, csv, parsing, save, xlsx

I have a series of CSV files that come to me bundled in a folder simply named for the month.  I've got code working to find them, open them, parse them and I'm having trouble saving them the way I want to.  What I'm aiming at is saving as the same file name as it was just in the new and parsed format.

```
Sub OpenCSVs_2()
Dim MyFiles As String, ThisMonth As String, Convert As String
Dim startPath As String
ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
startPath = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\CSV find convert tests\" & ThisMonth & "\"
MyFiles = Dir(startPath & "*.csv")
Convert = Dir(startPath & "*xlsx")

Do While MyFiles <> ""

Workbooks.Open startPath & MyFiles

Call Parse1

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="startPath & Convert",      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

MyFiles = Dir '<----------------error happens here

Loop

End Sub
```

The above actually does something and creates an xlsm file names "startPath & Convert".  I'm sure the solution is right in front of me.

Comment: While darnit isn't a major curse word, please try and keep a professional tone when writing posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with my previous post, you are putting your variables in quotes which then turns it into a string.  so first, remove the quotes on startPath & MyFiles, then just replace the extension using the function Replace.  I also added the Workbook object as you should avoid using Activeworkbook as it can cause issues.

```
Sub OpenCSVs_2()
Dim MyFiles As String, ThisMonth As String
Dim startPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
startPath = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\CSV find convert tests\" & ThisMonth & "\"
MyFiles = Dir(startPath & "*.csv")

Do While MyFiles <> ""

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(startPath & MyFiles)

    Call Parse1

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=startPath & Replace(MyFiles, ".csv", ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    MyFiles = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah... Replace is a predefined function.  This works... thanks so much.